# How can I get a browser tab to work hard without crashing?

Tags: browser, spam-prevention

I am trying to implement a proof of work mechanism similar to Bitcoin to prevent spam account registrations on a new website I am creating.

When you try to spam the account creation section of the site, you are forced to hash a signed message over and over again with an increasing nonce in order to find a low hash number and prove you have done some work... othwerise the site won't bother trying to process your registration attempt.

The code I have written works great... until it runs too long, and the tab eventually crashes (if I set the difficulty too high for example).

Is there any way to watch for and prevent this from crashing the browser tab? As it will be very annoying for the user to have to constantly refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this happens because you are doing some intensive work in the main thread of the browser.

The browser already has some mechanics to help us called [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), it's purpose is to off load work from the main thread.

I had a similar use case, and I used a web worker for that, more specifically this one: https://github.com/dtao/lemming.js.

For you though, I would suggest to invest some time on https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/comlink as has much more attention on github.